# Is it possible to access a document created using the intent with its path?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, uri

While working to upgrade to API 33 from API 28 I can no longer access the files that I have created with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent without using its URI.

I have tried making sure to ensure READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions were taken before attempting to access the file. I manage to create the file but when creating its path and trying to access it at that path the app suddenly fails to open it even though it should be the owner of that file if I'm not wrong?

I absolutely cannot use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission because that doesn't fit the usecase that I have.

Is there a way to use the path instead of the URI returned to write to the file? the file extension is csv.

Comment: Since Android 6.0 there is a bunch of changes in file storage usage. Seems like a ```FileProvider``` is a default way to do any kind of sharing on post android 6.0 versions. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: `but when creating its path` Well what does this mean? And of course you should not try to get a path for an uri. Use the uri as then you have read/write access. Even if you manage to find a file system path you will not have access on Android11+ devices. Only with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. But all is bad practice. Reuse the uri. Or use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user choose the file when needed.

Comment: What is your problem to reuse the uri?

Comment: @blackapps The problem requires me to utilize the path to open the file, the codebase can only accept a valid path.

Comment: While updating that code you should implement using uri. Nothing difficult.

Comment: Pretty strange an app uses ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT and then tries to find a path to write to. That was already wrong from the beginning. It's time you code it as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample to write and read the file.

Create the File:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCreateDocument);
intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
intent.SetType("application/txt");
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, "anew.txt");
StartActivity(intent);
```

Then I saved the file into the **Download Folder** by the system file manager and write the file.

```
File.WriteAllText("/storage/emulated/0/Download/anew.txt", "this is file content");
```

Every thing worked well after I granted the storage permission to my app. But when I saved the file in the **Documents Folder**, I will get the error about accessing path /storage/emulated/0/Documents/anew.txt is denied.

The read and write storage permission cann't access the Documentss Folder with a path.

Comment: I can use the uri to write the data directly, but when I attempt to use the path to that file to open it my access is denied. This happens specifically to the path.

Comment: Which folder did you put it in? @AmmarTK

Comment: I saved the document in the Downloads/ChildDir/Dir/

Comment: Just as my answer said, I have tested it. When I create the file in the download folder with the `Intent.ActionCreateDocument`, I can access it with the path. Did you try the code in my answer? @AmmarTK

Comment: I created my file using the same way you mentioned, but when attempting to write to it I get denied.

Comment: I tested it on the android simulator with android version 12.0. And it can works. Which kind of device did you test on? @AmmarTK

Comment: I tested it on Android 11

Comment: Did you granted your app the permission about storage？ @AmmarTK

Comment: I have mentioned the permissions that I granted in my post.

Comment: My careless, but the file can be accessed when I tested it.

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much but I attempted to store data in documents folder and it no longer denies access in Android 13.

And you don't need to create it via the picker either.

Comment: Can you access the file by the path now? @AmmarTK

Comment: Yes, Specifically for SDK 30+. You do not need permissions to create a folder in Documents. So I was able to solve my problem.

Comment: All right, happy coding!